# Почему фото не загружается на сайт?

Tags: html

Я только начинаю учить HTML, сходил на первый урок, на компьютере на курсах все работало, а когда запустил на своем компе, вместо изображения на странице появляется только thumbnail, причем цветные блоки появляются. Что не так? (Названия фото правильные).

```html
<div style="width:100%; height:70px; background-color: red;"></div>
<div></div>
<img src="photo1.jpg" style="width:100%; height:450px; border: 5px solid brown;">
<div></div>
<img src="monalisa.jpg" style="width:33.3%;">
<img src="monalisa.jpg" style="width:33%;">
<img src="monalisa.jpg" style="width:33%;">
<div style="width:100%; height:70px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

Comment: Неверно указан путь к файлу.

Comment: в каком смысле?

Comment: Если изображение в одной папке с html файлом, перед именем файла поставьте '/'

Comment: @MadFox как раз наоборот же... Если не указан путь, а лишь название изображения с расширением, то картинка ищется в той папке, где и страничка

Comment: Изображение в одной папке с файлом, но / не помог((

Comment: В смысле- "наоборот"? Со слешем перед именем будет искать в папке 'css'?

Comment: Поставьте перед именем файла точку со слешем - это указание на текущую директорию. Как-то так <img src="./monalisa.jpg" style=

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но ничего не помогает(